# Is it correct to use "but" as a positive connecting word?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, word-usage

I'm wondering if it is correct to use *but* as a positive connecting word. Below is a small example:

> ... is the perfect opportunity to improve my knowledge but also gain new experience with ...

Is this allowed or should I rather use *and*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*But* always contradicts, and is therefore almost always negative. You *can* use it as "positive connecting word", but only if it's contradicting a previous negatively-oriented statement:

> ... ***not only*** is this the perfect opportunity to improve my knowledge **but also** to gain new experience with ...

If it's not contradicting anything, don't use *but*. Use *and*.

Comment: I suggest you have a faulty parallelism there, and that you mean "It is the perfect opportunity not only to A but also to B."

Answer (score 2):

*But* is synonymous with *and*. I.e, if

- *Bill went early **but** he got back late.*

is true, then so is

- *Bill went early **and** he got back late.*

Ditto for when it's false. This is the definition of synonymy. Synonymy is a semantic relation; the difference between *but* and *and* is not semantic, but rather pragmatic.

One uses *but* instead of *and* when one wishes to express personal surprise at the conjunct following *but*, for whatever reason. Normally this is a matter of some expectation of the speaker's being violated, and the speaker may believe that the addressee has the same expectation and will be similarly surprised. This belief, of course, can be in error, like any belief.

*But*, however, is **not** negative per se; it does not [trigger NPIs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf). I.e, this is ungrammatical:

- **Bill got to the auction late but he bought anything.*

Answer (score 0):

*But* has a strong sense of contradiction or contrast. I don't think you can use it as a *positive connecting word*. The clauses you are connecting may have positive ideas but the use of *but* in connecting the clauses will always present a contradiction between them.

Answer (score 0):

An example of but being used in a positive way is

> All the songs were good, but Sweden's was the best.

> Liverpool is big, but London is bigger.